# Howto securely invoke a script on a remote server?

Tags: linux, server, ubuntu

I have an application running on a dedicated (Ubuntu) server. There is also a desktop GUI which functions as dashboard for the application. I want to be able to start and stop the application from the GUI. To stop it, I simply send a command to the applications which makes it end its execution.

Starting however is not so simple. I want to use a small bash-script for it, however I do not know how I can securely invoke the script on a remote server from a client machine. Assuming the client machine gets compromised, I do not want to have anything happen to the remote machine (for example stolen SSH credentials for a user who can upload/download/execute files on the remote machine).

How can I securely invoke that script?

Comment: please do not cross-post on StackExchange

Comment: My first question is why you would design your service in such a way that it requires the client to start it up. Why not use a server/client service model?

Comment: @schroeder I have now deleted my post on AskUbuntu. My application is only used by me and a collegue of mine. It is supposed to run 24/7, but it is not very far developed yet and crashes sometimes. I want my collegue to be able to restart it from the GUI when I am not at hand.

Comment: In that case can't you have it restart the process on crash ? I don't know the Linux commands for that but in windows task scheduler you can have it restart on crash so I assume you can on Linux.

Comment: @ISMSDEV yes, there are Linux commands to do the same

Comment: I wonder why is this question is being down voted, it is a concise and valid question

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to remotely execute an script you can just use `ssh server shell_script_path`. By using ssh you can just rely on its security.

If you do not need authentication to start/kill the service, maybe adding `Xinetd` entry will enable access control.

Comment: Two critical points in the question probably still need attention:
1. "Assuming the client machine gets compromised"
2. "for example stolen SSH credentials"
While using SSH built-in security is a good idea, will it cover a situation that involves both the above?

Comment: Right, he can just use password instead of asymmetric key exchange for ssh authentication

Comment: Still using the asymmetric key authentication he can delete it from the server if he thinks that the client machine has been compromised